# Best Practices for working with an indent-sensitive language?

Tags: indentation

pug, and python are both indent-sensitive languages.  I believe that if you have your editor correctly configured this can serve as an advantage, but if it is not correctly configured it's quite a bit of a nuisance.  Are there any settings I should have in my vim to make it easy to indent with the correct number of spaces each time I press tab to indent?

Comment: For supported fletypes: `filetype plugin indent on`.  That should take care of most nuisances.

Comment: This [fresh vim issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/989) could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `expandtab` is what you are looking for. It will make tab insert a number of spaces (defined by other options) instead of an actual tab.

See: `:h expandtab`, `:h shiftwidth`, `:h tabstop`, `:h softtabstop`, and `:h filetype-indent`. These are all that settings that affect tabs/indentation that I know of.